# How to select point mutations from MAF file

Tags: mutations, indel, maf, point-mutation

I am using [a mutation MAF file from GDC](https://portal.gdc.cancer.gov/files/a630f0a0-39b3-4aab-8181-89c1dde8d3e2).

I want to select for point mutations, therefore I selected `Variant_Classification` equal to `SNP`, and `Variant_Classification` equal to `INS` and `DEL` - but in this case I need to check against the size of the indel mutation.

How can I check for point mutations in the indel case? I think I have to work it out through checking the length of the fields in columns `Reference_Allele`, `Tumor_Seq_Allele1`, `Tumor_Seq_Allele2` but I am not sure if this is the best solution.